# Issue with my wordpress functions.php script

Tags: php

Im having an issues when activating my theme in wordpress. I got this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   $end in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\wordpress\wp-content\themes\xit\functions.php
>   on line 223

Whats wrong, I totally dont understand. The script of the php is:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));

  function content($num) {  
  $theContent = get_the_content();  
  $output = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $theContent);  
  $limit = $num+1;  
  $content = explode(' ', $output, $limit);  
  array_pop($content);  
  $content = implode(" ",$content)."...";  
  echo $content;  
}

function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null )
{
 foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
  // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
  $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category');
  if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}

//custom comments

function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">


     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
   <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
    <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='32',$default='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/61a58ec1c1fba116f8424035089b7c71?s=32&d=&r=G' ); ?>
   <?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?> <br /><?php printf(__('<strong>%s</strong> says:'), get_comment_author_link()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?></div>

      </div>
      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
         <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
         <br />
      <?php endif; ?>

      <div class="text"><?php comment_text() ?></div>

      <div class="reply">
         <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
      </div>
     </div>
<?php }
add_action('admin_menu', 'xit_theme_page');

function xit_theme_page ()
{
 if ( count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['xit_settings']) )
 {
  $options = array ( 'style','logo_img','logo_alt','logo_txt', 'logo_tagline', 'tagline_width', 'contact_email','ads', 'advertise_page', 'twitter_link', 'facebook_link', 'flickr', 'about_tit', 'about_txt', 'analytics');

  foreach ( $options as $opt )
  {
   delete_option ( 'xit_'.$opt, $_POST[$opt] );
   add_option ( 'xit_'.$opt, $_POST[$opt] ); 
  }   


 }
 add_theme_page(__('Xit Options'), __('Xit Options'), 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'xit_settings'); 
}
function xit_settings ()
{?>
<div class="wrap">
 <h2>XIT Options Panel</h2>

<form method="post" action="">
 <table class="form-table">
  <!-- General settings -->
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2"><strong>General Settings</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="style">Theme Color Scheme</label></th>
   <td>
    <select name="style" id="style">
     <option value="pink.css" <?php if(get_option('xit_style') == 'pink.css'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>pink.css</option>
     <option value="blue.css" <?php if(get_option('xit_style') == 'blue.css'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>blue.css</option>
     <option value="orange.css" <?php if(get_option('xit_style') == 'orange.css'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>orange.css</option>

    </select> 
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="logo_img">Logo image (full path to image)</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="logo_img" type="text" id="logo_img" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_logo_img'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="logo_alt">Logo image ALT text</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="logo_alt" type="text" id="logo_alt" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_logo_alt'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="logo_txt">Text logo</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="logo_txt" type="text" id="logo_txt" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_logo_txt'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
    <br /><em>Leave this empty if you entered an image as logo</em>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="logo_tagline">Logo Tag Line</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="logo_tagline" type="text" id="logo_tagline" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_logo_tagline'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="tagline_width">Tag Line Box Width (px)</label><br /><em style="font-size:11px">Default width: 300px</em></th>
   <td>
    <input name="tagline_width" type="text" id="tagline_width" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_tagline_width'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="contact_email">Email Address for Contact Form</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="contact_email" type="text" id="contact_email" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_contact_email'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="twitter_link">Twitter link</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="twitter_link" type="text" id="twitter_link" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_twitter_link'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="facebook_link">Facebook link</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="facebook_link" type="text" id="facebook_link" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_facebook_link'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="flickr">Flickr Photostream</label></th>
   <td>
    <select name="flickr" id="flickr">
     <option value="yes" <?php if(get_option('xit_flickr') == 'yes'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Yes</option>
     <option value="no" <?php if(get_option('xit_flickr') == 'no'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>No</option>
    </select> 
    <br /><em>Make sure you have FlickrRSS plugin activated if you choose to enable Flickr Photostream</em>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Sidebar ABout Box-->
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2"><strong>Sidebar About Box</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="about_tit">Title</label></th>
   <td>
    <input name="about_tit" type="text" id="about_tit" value="<?php echo get_option('xit_about_tit'); ?>" class="regular-text" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="about_txt">Text</label></th>
   <td>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="5" name="about_txt" type="text" id="about_txt" class="regular-text" /><?php echo get_option('xit_about_txt'); ?></textarea>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Ads Box Settings -->
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2"><strong>Ads Box Settings</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><label for="ads">Ads Section Enabled:</label></th>
   <td>
    <select name="ads" id="ads">
     <option value="yes" <?php if(get_option('xit_ads') == 'yes'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>Yes</option>
     <option value="no" <?php if(get_option('xit_ads') == 'no'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>No</option>
    </select> 
    <br /><em>Make sure you have AdMinister plugin activated and have the position "Sidebar" created within the plugin.</em>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <th scope="row"><label for="advertise_page">Advertise Page</label></th>
   <td>
    <?php wp_dropdown_pages("name=advertise_page&show_option_none=".__('- Select -')."&selected=" .get_option('xit_advertise_page')); ?>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <!-- Google Analytics -->
  <tr>
   <th><label for="ads">Google Analytics code:</label></th>
   <td>
    <textarea name="analytics" id="analytics" rows="7" cols="70" style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('xit_analytics')); ?></textarea>
   </td>
  </tr>


 </table>
 <p class="submit">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes" />
  <input type="hidden" name="xit_settings" value="save" style="display:none;" />
 </p>
</form>

</div>
<? }?>
<?php function get_first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img;


} ?>
```

The last line is line 223.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `?>` on this line `$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>`.

This causes PHP to stop reading the following to read as PHP code. The number of opening `<?php` doesn't match the number of closing `?>`

Comment: Ok. I got this from a friend. Im a noob basically. Erm....how to fix this issue? I'd sure like the help.

Comment: @iMayne, he already told you how to fix it. Delete the extra `?>` after `$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;` ....

Comment: I did but i got the same issue on line 34 which is: <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">

Comment: @iMayne - Its the _same_ problem, you have to get control over the scope of stuff that you want PHP to parse. For every `<?` , you need a corresponding `?>`. For every `?>` , you need a corresponding `<?`. Your editor should _probably_ be giving you hints, does the text all of a sudden change colors at a certain point?

Comment: thats: <li <?php comment_class();

Comment: Got it! Im so stupid! Goshhh!! The culprit was: <? }?>. It should have been: <?php } ?>

Thanks for the lession guys. You guys gave me some vital clues. Loving this site!!!

Comment: @iMayne , you might consider accepting thephpdeveloper's answer since it did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Im so stupid! Goshhh!! The culprit was: `<? }?>`. It should have been: `<?php } ?>` Thanks for the lession guys. You guys gave me some vital clues. Loving this site!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a spurious character or unnasigned piece coding - like a stray